# CSS's repeating-linear-gradient with multiple angles

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, angle, repeating-linear-gradient

I'm trying to create a repeating linear gradient with consecutive but inversed angles (alternating colors and angles). Is this posible? and how could I accomplish it? [image: Repeating linear gradient with multiple angles].
Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code that tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Those are two repeating linear-gradient:

```css
html {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 12deg, #0000 70%, #000 0), 
    linear-gradient(168deg, #0000 70%, #000 0);
  background-size: 100% 400px;
}
```